# How to save Checked Status of radio button in Quiz app using android studio with sharedpreferences

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button, sharedpreferences

I am making a quiz app in android studio. I am facing an issue which is that I have hundreds of questions with four options, and also next and previous buttons in that. For options, I am using radio buttons. I want that after the user selects an option for the first question, goes to the next question and selects an option for the second question, he will be able to go to the previous question, and there the radio button will be checked with the option the user has been selected earlier.

How can I do that? please help!

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    int score;
    float percentage;
    int answerSelected;


    private TextView quizQuestion,questionNumber;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private RadioButton optionOne;
    private RadioButton optionTwo;
    private RadioButton optionThree;
    private RadioButton optionFour;
    private ImageView question_image;
    private int currentQuizQuestion;
    private int quizCount;
    private QuizWrapper firstQuestion;


    private List<QuizWrapper> parsedObject;
    private boolean mIsDestroyed;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);



        score = 0;

        quizQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quiz_question);
        questionNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_number);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        optionOne = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        optionTwo = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        optionThree = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        optionFour = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        question_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.question_image);







        final Button previousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previousquiz);

        final Button nextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextquiz);

        AsyncJsonObject asyncObject = new AsyncJsonObject();

        asyncObject.execute("");


        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                int radioSelected = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                int userSelection = getSelectedAnswer(radioSelected);

                int correctAnswerForQuestion = firstQuestion.getIs_correct();

                if(userSelection == correctAnswerForQuestion){

// correct answer
                  score++;






                    //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You got the answer correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    currentQuizQuestion++;

                    if(currentQuizQuestion >= quizCount){

                        previousButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertConfirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        alertConfirm.setTitle("Confirm Submission");
                        alertConfirm.setMessage("Do you want to submit quiz?");
                        alertConfirm.setCancelable(true);
                        alertConfirm.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                        alertConfirm.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                              //  submit(view);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog dialog = alertConfirm.create();
                        dialog.show();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "End of the Quiz Questions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        return;

                    }

                    else{

                        previousButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      //  uncheckedRadioButton();
                        firstQuestion = parsedObject.get(currentQuizQuestion);

                        questionNumber.setText(Integer.toString(firstQuestion.getQuestion_number()));
                        quizQuestion.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestions());


                       if(firstQuestion.getQuestion_image().isEmpty()){

                          // Picasso.get().load(firstQuestion.getQuestion_image()).into(question_image);
                           question_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                       }else{
                           Picasso.get().load(firstQuestion.getQuestion_image()).into(question_image);
                           question_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       }

                      //  String[] possibleAnswers = firstQuestion.get.split(",");

                        optionOne.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_a());

                        optionTwo.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_b());

                        optionThree.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_c());

                        optionFour.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_d());





                    }

                }

                else{
                    currentQuizQuestion++;
                       // failed question
                   //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You chose the wrong answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 if(  currentQuizQuestion<quizCount) {
                     previousButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // uncheckedRadioButton();
                     firstQuestion = parsedObject.get(currentQuizQuestion);

                     questionNumber.setText(Integer.toString(firstQuestion.getQuestion_number()));
                     quizQuestion.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestions());


                     if(firstQuestion.getQuestion_image().isEmpty()){

                        // Picasso.get().load(firstQuestion.getQuestion_image()).into(question_image);
                         question_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                     }else{
                         Picasso.get().load(firstQuestion.getQuestion_image()).into(question_image);
                         question_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     }

                     //  String[] possibleAnswers = firstQuestion.get.split(",");


                     optionOne.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_a());
                     optionTwo.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_b());
                     optionThree.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_c());
                     optionFour.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_d());


                 }else {

                        AlertDialog.Builder alertConfirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        alertConfirm.setTitle("Confirm Submission");
                        alertConfirm.setMessage("Do you want to submit quiz?");
                        alertConfirm.setCancelable(true);
                        alertConfirm.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                        alertConfirm.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //  submit(view);
                                submit();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog dialog = alertConfirm.create();
                        dialog.show();

                      //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "End of the Quiz Questions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        return;
                    }

                }

            }

        });

        previousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (currentQuizQuestion <= 0) {

                    previousButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else {

                    currentQuizQuestion--;
                    firstQuestion = parsedObject.get(currentQuizQuestion);

                    questionNumber.setText(Integer.toString(firstQuestion.getQuestion_number()));
                    quizQuestion.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestions());

                    if (firstQuestion.getQuestion_image().isEmpty()) {

                        // Picasso.get().load(firstQuestion.getQuestion_image()).into(question_image);
                        question_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } else {
                        Picasso.get().load(firstQuestion.getQuestion_image()).into(question_image);
                        question_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    //     String[] possibleAnswers = firstQuestion.getAnswers().split(",");

                    optionOne.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_a());

                    optionTwo.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_b());

                    optionThree.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_c());

                    optionFour.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_d());



//                AlertDialog.Builder alertConfirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
//                alertConfirm.setTitle("Finish Test");
//                alertConfirm.setMessage("You cannot resume once you submit.Are you sure you want to submit this test?");
//                alertConfirm.setCancelable(true);
//                alertConfirm.setNegativeButton("RESUME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//
//                    }
//                });
//                alertConfirm.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                        //  submit(view);
//                        submit();
//                    }
//                });
//                AlertDialog dialog = alertConfirm.create();
//                dialog.show();
//
                }

            }
       });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mIsDestroyed = true;

        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private class AsyncJsonObject extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



        @Override

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());

            String url = "";

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String jsonResult = "";

            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

                System.out.println("Returned Json object " + jsonResult.toString());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return jsonResult;

        }

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading Quiz","Wait....", true);

        }


        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);



            System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            parsedObject = returnParsedJsonObject(result);

            if(parsedObject == null){

                return;

            }

            quizCount = parsedObject.size();


            firstQuestion = parsedObject.get(0);

            questionNumber.setText(Integer.toString(firstQuestion.getQuestion_number()));
            quizQuestion.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestions());


            if(firstQuestion.getQuestion_image().isEmpty()){

               // Picasso.get().load(firstQuestion.getQuestion_image()).into(question_image);
                question_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }else {

                Picasso.get().load(firstQuestion.getQuestion_image()).into(question_image);
                question_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

          //  String[] possibleAnswers = firstQuestion.getAnswers().split(",");

            optionOne.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_a());

            optionTwo.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_b());

            optionThree.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_c());

            optionFour.setText(firstQuestion.getOption_d());


        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            String rLine = "";

            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {

                while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    answer.append(rLine);

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return answer;

        }

    }

    private List<QuizWrapper> returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

        List<QuizWrapper> jsonObject = new ArrayList<QuizWrapper>();

        JSONObject resultObject = null;

        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        QuizWrapper newItemObject = null;

        try {

            resultObject = new JSONObject(result);

            System.out.println("Testing the water " + resultObject.toString());

            String test = "";

            jsonArray = resultObject.optJSONArray(test);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

            JSONObject jsonChildNode = null;

            try {

                jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                int id = jsonChildNode.getInt("id");


                String answera = jsonChildNode.getString("option_a");
                String answerb = jsonChildNode.getString("option_b");
                String answerc = jsonChildNode.getString("option_c");
                String answerd = jsonChildNode.getString("option_d");
                int correctAnswer = jsonChildNode.getInt("is_correct");
                int questionnumber = jsonChildNode.getInt("question_number");
                String question = jsonChildNode.getString("questions");
                String questionimage = jsonChildNode.getString("question_image");


                newItemObject = new QuizWrapper(id, answera,answerb,answerc,answerd, correctAnswer,questionnumber,question,questionimage);

                jsonObject.add(newItemObject);

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        return jsonObject;

    }

    private int getSelectedAnswer(int radioSelected){

         answerSelected = 0;

        radioGroup.clearCheck();

        if(radioSelected == R.id.radio0){



            answerSelected = 1;



        }

        if(radioSelected == R.id.radio1){



            answerSelected = 2;


        }

        if(radioSelected == R.id.radio2){

            answerSelected = 3;


        }

        if(radioSelected == R.id.radio3){

            answerSelected = 4;

        }

        return answerSelected;

    }

    private void uncheckedRadioButton() {

        optionOne.setChecked(false);

        optionTwo.setChecked(false);

        optionThree.setChecked(false);

        optionFour.setChecked(false);
    }





    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Back Press is not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    private void submit(){

       // if (submit)
          //  checkScore();
       // submit = false;
        percentage = (float) (score * 100) /parsedObject.size();
        //.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        optionOne.setClickable(false);
        optionTwo.setClickable(false);
        optionThree.setClickable(false);
        optionFour.setClickable(false);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
        final ProgressBar progressBar = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.circularProgressbar);
        final TextView textView = alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circular);
        progressBar.setMax(parsedObject.size());
        progressBar.setSecondaryProgress(parsedObject.size());
        progressBar.setProgress(score);
        progressBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
        textView.setText((int) percentage + "%");

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("RESULT");
        alert.setMessage("You scored " + score + " out of " + parsedObject.size() );
        alert.setView(alertLayout);
        alert.setCancelable(false);

        alert.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });

        alert.setPositiveButton("View Solutions", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //clickSolutions();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SolutionActivity.class);




                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Kotlin, but it's the same way to write in Java.

ShareReference Function:

```
private val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("YourFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Functions:

```
fun setInt(key: String, value: Int) {
    with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
        putInt(key, value)
        apply()
    }
}

fun getInt(key: String): Int {
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, -1)
}
```

Save the checked one:

```
// save to sharedPreferences
val CHECKED = "checkedRadio"
val checkedButtonId = radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId
setInt(CHECKED, checkedButtonId)
```

Load the checked one:

```
val mRatioId = getInt(CHECKED)
radioGroup.check(mRatioId)
```

Let's use it in the listener:

```
    val mRadioGroup = view?.findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id...)
    mRadioGroup?.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
        setInt(checkedId)
    }
```

Once you click any radio button, its radio-group will save the option to the shared preference. This code is saving R.id. But you can convert the id to ABCD.

static variables:

```
const val aRb = R.id.aRb
const val bRb = R.id.bRb
const val cRb = R.id.cRb
const val dRb = R.id.dRb
```

Instead saving integer. You can save it in string.

```
fun setString(key: String, value: String) {
    with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
        putString(key, value)
        apply()
    }
}

fun getString(key: String): String {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "")!!
}
```

Selection for Question # 12 as example:

```
when (checkedId) {
    aRb -> setString("Q12", 'a')   
    bRb -> setString("Q12", 'b')
    cRb -> setString("Q12", 'c')
    dRb -> setString("Q12", 'd')
}
```

Comment: where i need to add this funcation and methods in my given code